# Assembly (GNU Assembler) - Unexpected token in operand at "movl $0, %eax"

Tags: assembly, gcc

I would like to compile/assemble an assembly (.s) file that returns 0. To compile it, I am using `gcc -m32 -nostdlib file.s -o out`.

But I get the following errors:

```
file.s:3:14: error: unexpected token in operand
    movl $0, %eax
             ^
file.s:4:5: error: invalid instruction
    ret
    ^
```

When I run `gcc -m32 -v`, it says the target is **"arm-apple-darwin21.1.0"**, if that could help answering my question.

Here is my assembly:

file.s

```
 .globl main
main:
    movl   $0, %eax
    ret
```

Any ideas on how I could solve this? Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: You seem to be on an ARM system but this is x86 code. They are not compatible. Use ARM code, e.g. `mov r0, #0; bx lr` Also if you want to use `main` then do not use `-nostdlib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, thanks to everyone who came by this question.
As Jester said in the comment section, it was just my assembly code not being compatible with an ARM system.

Comment: Note also that an Apple M1 cannot run 32 bit ARM code.  So if you want to learn ARM assembly on your Apple computer, learn 64 bit ARM assembly.